# CURL PHP v5.2.9

Tags: php, curl, centos

When I do a `phpinfo();` below the warning about cURL :

> *SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.*

My server is in 5.2.9 PHP version with centOS, do you think I have to reinstall curl ??

Comment: Are you doing anything to do with Facebook? A quick Google search shows Facebook shows that error.

Comment: It's not relink with Facebook, it's for CURL

Comment: Show a screenshot of that error message please.

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/qs7CfaqTgpU

Comment: Does the script contain something else apart from the `phpinfo()` call, such as e.g. a full HTML document with some other code?